# Product type for me? Grouped bundle?

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products

We have installed Magento CE 1.9.0.1 and i am playing around with product options to do what i want it to do.

Basically its the Grouped Product that i need but i don't want to show the individual products.

Example

"Product 1"
 - "Product 1 - Box1"
 - "Product 1 - Box2"

So, i want to be able to control the stock of "Box1" and "Box2" but have all other information/prices in the main product ("Product 1") but on the front end the customer doesn't need to see the 2x boxes that are being added to the order.

Does that make sense?

Does anyone know if i can do this out of the box or if they can recommend a plugin to do this?

Maybe a new Product Type would work?

Please advise.

Regard,
Martin

Comment: I would use CSS to hide any product info showing on the page

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to make a Bundle Product instead? Bundle products are the exact same as grouped products, except you have the option to let customers not choose the quantity of sub-products they can order.

In the default Magento demo store the [Sony VAIO 11.1" Notebook PC](http://screencast.com/t/V2cZdkgExeX) is an example of a bundle product. [Here's how I've configured it.](http://screencast.com/t/iduNT7r9z)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi there,I have been playing with the bundle product type and it comes close, but its not quite what we are after.   we need to show just the main product but keep the boxes invisible to the end user.

Comment: You can hide the other boxes with css. Add a "display:none" to them :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the grouped format without having to make a new product type with a few changes:

(default theme)
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

```
<?php $this->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable() && $_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra') ?>
<table class="data-table grouped-items-table" id="super-product-table">
    <col />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></td>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <td class="a-center">
            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
       <tr>
           <td colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('No options of this product are available.') ?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('super-product-table')</script>
```

replace the hidden input qty value with 1 if you always want 1 item of each sub product.

[image: Product Table]

Next you need to modify the product view
(default theme)
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
    <?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post"
              id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
            <div class="no-display">
                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value=""/>
            </div>

            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                    <?php
                    // if it's grouped
                    if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped') {

                        // get the associated products
                        $associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product);

                        foreach ($associatedProducts as $item) {

                            // get the final price of each item
                            $finalPrice[] = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($item, $item->getFinalPrice(), true);

                        }

                        // show the sum as a price
                        echo "Price:" . Mage::helper('core')->currency(array_sum($finalPrice), true, false);

                    }?>
                </div>

                <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                    <p class="email-friend"><a
                            href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true) ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

                <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()): ?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()): ?>
                    <div class="short-description">
                        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>

                        <div
                            class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other'); ?>

                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>

            <div class="product-img-box">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
            </div>

            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function (button, url) {
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    var form = this.form;
                    var oldUrl = form.action;

                    if (url) {
                        form.action = url;
                    }
                    var e = null;
                    try {
                        this.form.submit();
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                    this.form.action = oldUrl;
                    if (e) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

            productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function (button, url) {
                if (this.validator) {
                    var nv = Validation.methods;
                    delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                    // Remove custom datetime validators
                    for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                        if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                            delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                        }
                    }

                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        if (url) {
                            this.form.action = url;
                        }
                        this.form.submit();
                    }
                    Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
            //]]>
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
        <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html): ?>
            <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}" ?>">
                <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')): ?>
                    <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $html; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Grouped Product]

You would need to add in some additional logic:

- Handle things like out of stock on the child products
- Checkout/cart display templates use getParentIdsByChild() to test if it's a child
- Redirecting simple product pages to their parents (modifying the product controller)

That would cover most of it.